# Неправильный результат работы кода

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

После ввода всех данных программа выводит одно число, непонятно откуда взявшееся, но для одних и тех же данных одинаковое, и одно вообще каждый раз новое, при этом намного больше чем вообще может быть.
Задание состоит вот в чём: "Дано квадратную матрицу размером NxN, найти сумму элементов и максимальный элемент в заштрихованной области (квадрат поделённый на четыре части диагоналями, и один из треугольников заштрихован)"

В идеале задачу надо решить используя указатели, но я пока с ними не разобрался.
Вот мой код

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    char chek [256];
    int sum = 0;
    int n, max = 0,i,j;
    cout << "Ââåäèòå N" << endl;
    cin >> chek;
    n = atoi(chek);
    int matrica [n][n];
    cout << "Ââåäèòå ýëåìåíòû ìàòðèöû" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cin >> matrica [i][j];
        }
    }
    switch(n%2){
        case 0: 
            for( i = 0; i < (n/2); i++){
                for( j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                    sum+=(matrica[i][j]);
                    if(matrica[i][j] > max){
                        max = (matrica[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for( i = (n/2); i < n; i++){
                for( j = n-i-1; j >= 0; j--){
                    sum+=matrica[i][j];
                    if(matrica[i][j] > max){
                        max = matrica[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << "Ñóììà âñåõ ýëåìåíòîâ ìàññèâà â âûäåëåííîé â çàäà÷å ÷àñòè = " << sum << endl;
            cout << "Ìàêñèìàëüíûé ýëåìåíò ìàññèâà â âûäåëåííîé â çàäà÷å ÷àñòè = " << max << endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            for( i = 0; i <= n/2; i++){
                for( j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                    sum+=matrica[i][j];
                    if(matrica[i][j] > max){
                        max = matrica[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            for( i = n/2; i <= n; i++){
                for( j = n/2; j >= 0; j--){
                    sum+=matrica[i][j];
                    if(matrica[i][j] > max){
                        max = matrica[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << "Ñóììà âñåõ ýëåìåíòîâ ìàññèâà â âûäåëåííîé â çàäà÷å ÷àñòè = " << sum << endl;
            cout << "Ìàêñèìàëüíûé ýëåìåíò ìàññèâà â âûäåëåííîé â çàäà÷å ÷àñòè = " << max << endl;
            break;

    }
}
```

Как сумму программа выводит число вообще непонятно откуда взявшееся, а как максимальное, вообще числа на 5 порядков больше чем я вводил

UPD. После того как я при инициализации сделал присваивание переменной для максимального числа значения 0, максимум стал правильно работать, но с суммой элементов это не помогло

UPD2. Если сделать массив из одного элемента равного единице, сумма выводится 2, а при попытке все нужные элементы на вводе задавать 1, а ненужные 0, сумма вместо, например 6, выходит 8
Вообще не понимаю в чём проблема

UPD3. Исправил сравнения, но для нечётных N вообще не работает, выводит огромные числа

Comment: У вас переменная sum нигде не инициализируется. Начните исправление с этого.

Comment: Инициализируется, во второй строке main'а

Comment: Или нужно ей присвоить хоть какое-то значение?

Comment: Нужно присвоить. Во второй строке вы только объявляете, что она есть, а значение у нее получается такое, какое было в оперативке в этом месте в этот момент - то есть, любое.

Comment: Ну с максимумом это помогло, но сумму всё ещё неправильно считает

Comment: У вас там бардак в индексах и размерах матриц. Вы в начале сперва от введенного пользователем вычитаете 1, потом прибавляете 1 - нафига? Наверняка у вас где-то в условиях циклов также напуано.

Comment: Пользователь вводит, допустим 4, для того, чтобы потом удобнее было в условиях использовать размер массива, я отнимаю единицу, потому что массив начинается с нуля, а потом при инициализации массива добавляю один, чтобы массив создался размера который указал пользователь
Написанно запутанно, но вроде правильно

Comment: обычно используют строгое сравнение `i < n` в циклах, а не жонглирование с единицей

Comment: Вообще да, я с этим очень сильно прокололся

Answer (score 1):

Задачу решил, действительно, были проблемы в условиях циклов, в чётном надо было связать j с i, а в нечётном массиве было очень много ошибок в условиях

Вот итоговый код

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    char chek [256];
    int sum = 0;
    int n, max = 0,i,j;
    cout << "Ââåäèòå N" << endl;
    cin >> chek;
    n = atoi(chek);
    int matrica [n][n];
    cout << "Ââåäèòå ýëåìåíòû ìàòðèöû" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cin >> matrica [i][j];
        }
    }
    switch(n%2){
        case 0: 
            for( i = 0; i < (n/2); i++){
                for( j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                    sum+=(matrica[i][j]);
                    if(matrica[i][j] > max){
                        max = (matrica[i][j]);
                    }
                }
            }
            for( i = (n/2); i < n; i++){
                for( j = n-i-1; j >= 0; j--){
                    sum+=matrica[i][j];
                    if(matrica[i][j] > max){
                        max = matrica[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << "Ñóììà âñåõ ýëåìåíòîâ ìàññèâà â âûäåëåííîé â çàäà÷å ÷àñòè = " << sum << endl;
            cout << "Ìàêñèìàëüíûé ýëåìåíò ìàññèâà â âûäåëåííîé â çàäà÷å ÷àñòè = " << max << endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            for( i = 0; i <= (n-1)/2; i++){
              for( j = 0; j <= i; j++){
                sum+=matrica[i][j];
                if(matrica[i][j] > max){
                  max = matrica[i][j];
                }
             }
        }
      for( i = (n-1)/2 + 1; i <= n-1; i++){
         for( j = n - i - 1; j >= 0; j--){
            sum+=matrica[i][j];
                if(matrica[i][j] > max){
                        max = matrica[i][j];
                    }
                }
           }
            cout << "Ñóììà âñåõ ýëåìåíòîâ ìàññèâà â âûäåëåííîé â çàäà÷å ÷àñòè = " << sum << endl;
            cout << "Ìàêñèìàëüíûé ýëåìåíò ìàññèâà â âûäåëåííîé â çàäà÷å ÷àñòè = " << max << endl;
            break;

    }
}
```